# Open Google MyMaps, with specifics

Tags: google-maps, mymaps

I have both a standard Google Map, and Google MyMap working within a portal in FileMaker  ... but the My Map is not working quite the way I want.  I simply want a URL that I can specify any / all of these parameters:

My Map ID
Addr to center on (hopefully with a pin or some indicator)
Lat Long is available if needed
Zoom = 17

The problem is that when I specify it in My Maps, using

"&q=" with address, and/or, sll= or ll= with long lat

it doesn't center on the address nor the long lat -- and it works just fine if I use standard Google Maps instead of My Map

I've tried specifying the size for the map, but see no difference.

Any ideas how to center the map on the address specified when using My Map?

Thanks!
Neil

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

For my maps, you need to update the underlying map. It does not accept query params in the url as far as I can tell.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Can you elaborate on "you need to update the underlying map" ... what are you meaning?  Is there a way to have a mymap overlay on regular google maps?

Comment: you can use the kml network link to add to a dynamic map `new google.maps.Map` https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/kml#KmlLayer